# Good app for a wish list?

Tags: webapp-rec, amazon, wish-list

I love Amazon's wish list, but I have a few items I want to record that aren't available on Amazon.

Is there another app that does something similar and/or a way to add items that aren't listed on Amazon to my Amazon wish list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually add things to your Amazon wishlists that are not available on the site using a bookmarklet by using use their universal wish-list service

http://www.amazon.co.uk/wishlist/universal/ref=wl_eywl_uwl

Based on your description "I love Amazon's wishlist" I would say this would be a good option for you

Answer (score 0):

[Wishlistr](http://www.wishlistr.com/home/) can do this and supports importing public wishlists from Amazon and Delicious. The downside is that it doesn't support letting people tick items off, so you'll have to remove items manually.

Answer (score 0):

Google [spreadsheets](http://spreadsheets.google.com/) is pretty nice. You can create a form for easy input and you can create a link for others to view. A mobile site is also available.

Answer (score 0):

There a social wishlist app at http://wishd.me - you can create and share wishlists with your friends.

Comment: Can you add a disclosure if you work for the company or why else it's a good match for the question. Link only with small amounts of description aren't a good match for this community.